# How to render items in react native FlatList with 2 columns when some of them must be full width

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to render product list in React Native with 2 columns by default, but if any item is a special product, then make it full width.

```
const data = [
{id: '1', name: 'Item1', price: 25, special_product: false},
{id: '2', name: 'Item2', price: 15, special_product: false},
{id: '3', name: 'Item3', price: 11, special_product: true},
{id: '4', name: 'Item4', price: 22, special_product: false},
{id: '5', name: 'Item5', price: 32, special_product: false},
{id: '6', name: 'Item6', price: 22, special_product: false},
{id: '7', name: 'Item7', price: 22, special_product: false},
]
```

And I want to get FlatList structure like this:

```
[Item 1][Item2]

[Special Item3]

[Item4] [Item5]

[Item6] [Item7]
```

My code is really simple now:

```
<FlatList
      ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      horizontal={false}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={({ id }) => id}
      onRefresh={this.onListRefresh}
      refreshing={refreshing}
      renderItem={this.renderItems}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyList.bind(this, data, use)}
    />
```

My item container styles looks like this:

```
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 0.5,
    margin: Layout.Margin.Narrow,
    shadowColor: ShadowColor.Standard,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
  },
...
    });
```

Item that is rendered by `renderItem` function:

```
// Item
...
return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => console.log('user clicked on the item')}>

      <View style={{ 
        ...itemStyle.container
      }}
           <StyledText
            type={"small"}
            numberOfLines={1}
            allowFontScaling={false}
            style={itemStyle.centerText}>
            {name}
          </StyledText>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

How can I do this? I'm using React Native v0.60.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the number of columns prop and provide a width of 100% this will give the output you need.

This is a working sample you can apply it your item styles in anyway you need.

Flatlist code

```
  <FlatList
    numColumns={2}
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Item
        id={item.id}
        title={item.name}
        selected={item.special_product}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  />
```

Render item function

```
function Item({ id, title, selected }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {}}
      style={[
        selected ? { width: '100%' } : { width: '50%' },
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}>
      <Text style={{}}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

As you can see I've set the width conditionally based the selected flag.